# Homology of $X\times S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'd like to show that for a topological space $X$,
$$H_\ast(X\times S^n)\cong H_\ast(X)\oplus H_{\ast}(X\times S^n,X\times\{x_0\}).$$

It's obvious that the LES obtained from the SES of the pair has to be used, i.e.
$$\rightarrow H_\ast(X)\overset{\iota_\ast}{\rightarrow} H_\ast(X\times S^n)\overset{\pi_\ast}{\rightarrow} H_\ast(X\times S^n,X\times\{x_0\})\rightarrow$$
with $\iota,\pi$ inclusion and projection, respectively. If this would split into SESs then the result would be obvious from the Splitting Lemma, however, I don't see why this should be the case.

I'd be grateful for any hints or explanations.

Comment: Do you know about the relative Künneth formula? This should be the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: @RobinCarlier I have, but I'm not at all familiar with it. I was hoping to solve this by using LESs of pairs and Mayer-Vietoris only...